# How to calculate temporal change over time when response is 0 or 1 in r

Tags: r, temporal

What would be the best approach to calculate the temporal change in response that has values 0 or 1 over time? For example, I have data `df` with years `yr` and response `res` for a station A. How can I know if the change on response over time is positive (increasing) or negative (decreasing) or not change at all. what statistical tool would be better? This data actually shows the response of an atmospheric phenomenon on the extreme weather event as of whether the phenomenon was present when the extreme occurs or not.

```
df<-structure(list(yr = c(1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 
1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 
1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 
1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 
1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 
2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010), 
    res = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)), .Names = c("yr", "res"), row.names = c(NA, 
-61L), class = "data.frame")
```

PS: same question i posted in cross Validated, not sure where it best fit.

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point is a logit or probit regression.  Here's probit code in R:

```
summary(glm(res ~ yr, data=df))
```

For your example data, you'll get a positive but statistically insignificant (at usual levels) coefficient on year.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain or suggest me some reference on how you got insignificantly increasing using the probit model. Do I have to perform time dependency calculation with time ie temporal change= exp((beta0+beta1*t)/(1-(beta0+beta1*t)) where beta0 and beta1 are coefficients of the model ?

Comment: The coefficients of a nonlinear model (like a probit) take a little more work to interpret than those from a simple linear regression, but the sign and significance of the coefficients can be read "straight" from the `summary` output.  For more on probits, I think Gary King at Harvard provides excellent explanations and teaching materials.  See, for example, [this paper](https://gking.harvard.edu/files/gking/files/making.pdf) or pick up [this book](https://www.press.umich.edu/script/press/23784).